# page layout problem

Tags: margins, double-sided

I have a knotty (at least for me) problem to solve.

I do apologize, I'm a beginner. I'm trying to find a solution to misalignment.

My document is as follows:

```
page 1
  xxxxxxxxxxxx
  xxxxxxxxxxxx
  xxxxxxxxxxxx 

page 2
xxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

But what I'd like is:

```
page 1
 xxxxxxxxxxxx
 xxxxxxxxxxxx
 xxxxxxxxxxxx 
 page 2
 xxxxxxxxxxxx
 xxxxxxxxxxxx
 xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The preamble is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{report}
%\documentclass[a4paper,singleside,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{ia_urb_thesis}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath


\begin{document}

\titolo{Title ...
\\[5mm]
        }
\candidato{io}
\relatore{Chiar.mo Prof.~}
\annoaccademico{000}




\copertinatesi

\dedica{Ai miei genitori}
\indice
\indicefigure
\indicetabelle
\iniziatesto

\include{cap_1}
\include{cap_2}


\appendix
\include{app_a}
\include{biblio}

\ringraziamenti
bla bla  ...

\end{document}
```

What's wrong with that?

Comment: remove the `twoside` option which asks for different layout on odd and even pages.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `twoside` option which asks for different layout on odd and even pages.